# How to create buffer sequence

Tags: c++, boost-asio

There is `boost::asio::buffer` that creates buffer sequence with only one element. Is there any wrapper that allows to create buffer sequence from several buffers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no wrapper, but you can provide multiple buffers in any container that meets the [MutableBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html) and [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) concepts requirements, such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, or `boost::array`.  Most functions are implemented in terms of the BufferSequence concepts, and [`boost::asio::buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) provides a conveinent way to wrap a single buffer into a type that meets the requirements.  This [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html) briefly mentions it.

Here is a snippet from the Boost.Asio serialization [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/connection.hpp):

```
// Write the serialized data to the socket. We use "gather-write" to send
// both the header and the data in a single write operation.
std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffers, handler);
```

Note that the `buffers` collection does not need to remain in scope, as the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) states that Boost.Asio may create copies as necessary.  However, the underlying memory , `outbound_header_` and `outbound_data_`, need to remain valid until the handler is called.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. The asio documentation is a little sparse.

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury The code snippet(demo for ConstBufferSequence) aforementioned seems **does not work any more**.  Here is the [test](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e638ec00870636dc). The bytes to be sent is 13 whereas the handler functions tells 32!

Comment: @John Your code, unlike this answer, wraps the overall `buffers` argument in `asio::buffer()`. But only the individual component buffers should use that function (as shown here). By doing that, you are asking for the elements in your top-level `send_buffers` vector to be treated as a flat array of bytes. Each element is a `boost::asio::const_buffer`, which has two 8-byte members on a 64-bit system (data and size), so is 16 bytes in total. There are two elements in the vector, so there are 32 bytes in total to send.